# Load a matrix from a file

Tags: c++

Ive got this HW problem im really stumpped on. I need to load this matrix from a file.

```
class matrix 
{
public:
    matrix(matrix& other); //copy constructor

    ~matrix(); //destructor

    void LoadMatrix(string filename);

    //load data from file into m

    bool operator==(matrix& other); //compare two matrix

private:
    int** m; //2D dynamic array of integers

    int height; //height of m

    int width; //width of m
};
```

The `LoadMatrix` function load data from a data file, the data file contains data like:

```
2 3 
1 2 3
3 4 8
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
class matrix 
{
public:
    matrix(matrix& other); //copy constructor

    ~matrix(); //destructor

    void LoadMatrix(string filename);

    //load data from file into m

    bool operator==(matrix& other); //compare two matrix

private:
    int** m; //2D dynamic array of integers

    int height; //height of m

    int width; //width of m
};

matrix::matrix()
{
}

matrix::~matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        delete m[i];
    }
    delete m;
}

void matrix::LoadMatrix(string filename)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        string line1 = "", line2 = "";
        infile >> height;
        infile >> width;
        infile.ignore();
        m = new int*[height];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            m[i] = new int[width];
            line2 = "";
            getline(infile, line1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
}
```

Any tips would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Read `n`, read `m`, read `n` lines of `m` integers into an array. What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you format your code like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real question here except it does not work, it does not compile, why ?

As the first line of the matrix in the file seems to define the height and width of the matrix and considering you only store integers in it, you simply have to perform a double for-loop to store values in each line.

Probably something like this:

```
void LoadFromFile(const std::string& iFile)
{
    std::ifstream infile(iFile);
    infile >> _height;      
    infile >> _width;
    _m = new int*[_height];
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; ++i)      
    {
        _m[i] = new int[_width];         
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; ++j)     
        {
            infile >> _m[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you must not trust data provided in a file so some checks have to be added in the previous code.